# How to delete everything in an AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to nuke all existing settings in an AWS account to begin again on a clean slate?

I an AWS beginner and after getting tangled up and my web site no longer loading, I need a clean slate to start afresh i.e. delete all **AIM**, **ECS**, **S3**, **Load balancers** etc all in one go.

Comment: Not in one step. Not without deleting the entire account. You'll have to go through and delete things one service at a time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably not. This is a common safety + security mechanism in such complex and important systems: nobody should be able, by accident or otherwise, to quickly and easily delete everything. Using an [infrastructure as code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_Code) process, however, you would be able to do this by simply declaring the entire stack as unwanted. This is relatively safe for the simple reason that you can usually bring this kind of infrastructure back up again in a short time span, as long as care was taken during development to make sure that any permanent state cannot be irrevocably destroyed by infrastructure declaration changes.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke - it can clean everything from every region and is the best tool I've found yet!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).